# Evaluate Complex Line Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate $\int _C f$ where $f(z)=x^2+iy^2$ and where $C$ is given by $z(t)=t^2+it^2, 0\leq t \leq 1$.

I tried reading an example in the book, using the formula $\int_C f(z)dt=\int_a^bf(z(t))\dot{z}(t)dt$, but I am not sure how to proceed.  I know that $\dot{z}(t)=2t+2it$ but I do not understand what is mean by $f(z(t))$.  This is the first time I have seen composition of complex functions.  Is it as simple as substituting the real part of $z(t)$ into the real part of $f$ and similarly with the imaginary parts?  That is, does $f(z(t))=t^4+it^4$?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Exactly, that's the idea.

Comment: Thank you.  But what about a situation for example, where $f(z)=(x+iy)^2=x^2-y^2+2ixy$ and $z(t)=t^2+it^2$.  How is the substitution $f(z(t))$ done in this case?

Comment: So if you have $f(z)=z^2$, just plug in your $z(t)$, and you can expand into real/complex parts. Otherwise, $x$ is the real part of $z$, $iy$ is the imaginary part. So if you have $z=t^2+it^2$, with $t$ real, then $t^2$ is the real part, $it^2$ is the imaginary part. So $x=y=t^2$ again.